# Creating a room with Firebase for a web app

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently building a web app based in firebase and want users the ability to create and join game rooms. Currently i am having an issue trying to figure out how to create the room where others can join. I was wondering if anyone can help me get started on this issue. Just an FYI each user who will be creating and joining the room will have their own account with unique ID if that matters

Comment: Hi, you can start Firebase Authentification(s): https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ which means that your rooms won't be accesible unless logged in through Firebase or both your app and Firebase

Comment: Currently i have it so that you must be logged in to have the option show up for create or join room

Comment: Ok good, so what's your issue then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have any concept of rooms. There are parent and child nodes which are code wise handled through key: value pairs, very similar to a Dictionary.

There are also no users in Firebase either, other than the user id's (uid) and associated data that are created when new user is created in Firebase and stored internally on the server. That data is used for authentication. If other data needs to be stored about a user, a name perhaps, it's done within the database itself.

Keeping it simple, let's say we want to store information about users and rooms.

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Bill"
  uid_1
    name: "Ted"
  uid_27
    name: "The Doctor"
```

The uid's are the ones that are created when a new user creates an account in Firebase. Your app will collect the uid that Firebase provides and write it and any other user data to the users node; in this case the users name.

Then the rooms

```
rooms
   room_0
     room_name: "Phone Booth"
     description: "Time travelling in style; Excellent!"
     uid_0: true
     uid_1: true
   room_1
     room_name: "Tardis"
     description: "It's bigger on the inside"
     uid_27: true
```

In this case room_0, the Phone Booth, has both Bill and Ted in it and room_1 has The Doctor in it.

This is not the only way to structure the data and your structure may vary from this a lot, but it's a place to start.

Note: key names should almost always be created with push(). I used room_0 etc as a placeholder. Best practice is to disassociate main parent key names from the data it contains. i.e. don't hard code key names with something like an email address - that's bad news.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps a ton. Just to clarify with the push() function that would be called whenever the user creates the room. The room would then would be assigned just some value to refer to correct?

Comment: @jhigg15 Correct!